# Pushing hashes into array. Want to update count on same name atttr. hashes

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I am pushing hashes into an array. Some hashes will be the same - contain all the same values. In those cases, I want to NOT push the hash in, BUT update the original hash with a count of +1.

for example.

```
var hashes = {};
var newHashes = {};

// in this case, 'h' is a key that CAN exists later on again
hashes[h] = {
   val1: 'val1',
   val2: 'val2'
}

jQuery.extend(true, newHashesContainer, h)
someArray.push(h)
```

ok. some time later, I have the same content and I am pushing it into the PUSH_ARRAY function

```
if (newHashContainer[h]) hashes[h].count++
```

// I know it exists already so I want to now add an attribute of count to it, and increment every time  the same key hash comes in. I can't seem to wrap my brain around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create the property if it doesn't already exist and then you can increment it's value.

So, if you've already checked that `hashes[h]` has the value you want and you just want to increment a count on that object, you can create and increment the count like this:

```
if (newHashContainer[h]) {
    // Assumes that prior code has already make sure
    // that hashes[h] exists
    // Here, we just make sure that the .count property exists
    // and then increment it
    if (!hashes[h].count) {
        hashes[h].count = 0;
    }
    hashes[h].count++
}
```

Your question doesn't make it clear what `newHashContainer[h]` does, but I'm assuming that it makes sure the new hash is in the `hashes` object.  If that's not what it does, please explain further exactly what you need help with or what that function does.

Comment: I apologize I can't upvote or accept as I do not have enough rep, or I would. Thanks!